# Entity framework Linq Include() nested with conditions

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have a product, this product can have some descriptions one by language.

I'd like based on the `product.Reference` and the `Language.Code` get the product and the description matching the language code. I use EF Core 2.0

I can do it with 2 separated query but I'd like one if it's possible.

I tried this :

```
var product = _context.Products
    .Where(x => x.Reference == "3265709")
    .Include(x => x.ProductDescriptions)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.Where(lg => lg.Language.Code == "EN").Select(z => z.Language))
    .ToList();
```

Any idea ?

Thanks,

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Reference { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductDescription> ProductDescriptions{ get; set; }
}

public class ProductDescription
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Short { get; set; }
    public string Complete { get; set; }
    public Language Language{ get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}

public class Language
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the two queries you used?

Comment: I see how do it in two queries but didn't do yet. I'd like in one query first.

Comment: Your question isn't crystal clear (to me at least). If you show the two-query solution it might help others with understanding what it is exactly that you need.

Comment: not  crystal clear ? just the Linq query to get product (and one description matching the language) based on the product reference and the language of the description.

Answer (score 1):

Could you do something like this? You might not even need the `.Any()` part.

```
var product = _context.Products.Where(x => x.Reference == "3265709" && x.ProductDescriptions.Any(a => a.Language.Code == "EN"))
   .SelectMany(x => x.ProductDescriptions.Where(z => z.Language.Code == "EN").Select(a => a.Language)).ToList();
```

EDIT:

Is this what you are looking for then? This should give you a list of products with the Reference code specified and a filtered Product Description list based on the language code.

```
var product = _context.Products.Where(x => x.Reference == "3265709" && x.ProductDescriptions.Any(a => a.Language.Code == "EN")).Select(x => new Product {
      Id = x.Id,
      Name = x.Name,
      ProductDescriptions = x.ProductDescriptions.Where(a => a.Language.Code == "EN").ToList(),
      Reference = x.Reference
});
```

Comment: The result is a language not a Product with the ProductDescription but there are some ideas to take

Comment: Oh I thought based on this part of your linq .Select(z => z.Language) that you wanted to return a list of Languages.

Comment: I put in some new code, hope this is what you were looking for

Comment: Why not but recreate the product object I lose the other 'include' I have

Comment: I thought you were asking for products matching the product.Reference and had a product description that had a language code EN only. Doesnt my code provide this? Why are you using Includes?